# R Session Aborted and R encountered a fatal error

Tags: r, rstudio, r-xlsx, error-messages-for

I have been using Rstudio for a while and there was no problem until I was trying to install rJava and xlsx package in R. I had updated both my RGui and Rstudio to the latest version (also downloaded java x64 bit for my desktop since earlier I had a Java_Home error message trying to install both rJava and xlsx package) and I was able to install both rJava and xlsx in Rstudio, but when I use

`library(xlsx)`

I encountered the R session aborted message. This happen every time even when I already closed the application and tried to open it again.

I'm currently using 2022.02.2 Build 485 for my Rstudio and 4.20.0 for my RGui. Anyone knows what I can do with this?

edit: I ended up using a different package to read my excel file (read_excel) for my data which worked very well. However, I still don't know what is the problem with my 'xlsx' package

Comment: Does it work outside of RStudio?

Comment: @user2554330 it works outside of RStudio. In the end I used read_excel instead since I can load the package with no problem, but I still haven't found out the problem with the xlsx package

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been discussed in RStudio Community
https://community.rstudio.com/t/package-xlsx-error/136288

You should install a patched version
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. I uninstalled R and R Studio, then reinstalled them, and it worked well